# Where does git install Vim on windows 7?

Tags: git, vim, windows-7

I've installed Git without adding the "UNIX features" however when I run `git commit` it opens up vim, and I wonder, where is this program installed?

I looked in the `/bin` directory of my git installation, but didn't find it. Since I didn't install the UNIX features, running `vim` in the commandline doesn't work.

**NOTE:** I'm using the windows commandline not the Git bash. Git bash is installed but I'm not using it.

Comment: they are there in git tree, with some prefix. Search for vim.exe

Comment: `$ which vim` will tell you where Vim is.

Comment: `which vim` only works if vim was added to path, which it wasn't. You can choose when you install to install the unix shorthands for the commandline (note not the bash!) and I chose not to, however, it's still installed and set to the default editor for git.

Answer (score 2):

You can find vim under `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` or `path-to-git-installation/usr/bin` if you installed it elsewhere.